# ListView Sort doesn't work OnClick (PowerShell)

Tags: winforms, sorting, listview, powershell

I have a ListView on a form built in PowerShell which I just can't get sorted.

If I call $LV.Sort() from the command line (while the form is not shown) it works perfectly fine. However if I try to call it in an OnClick event on anything on the form it doesn't. I've put flags in and I know that section of code is running, it's just not doing anything or flagging any errors.

Obviously `$LV.Sorting = "Ascending"` is set otherwise it wouldn't be sorting at all, and I can change the items so the reference to the ListView is fine. Also tried invoking in case of a threading issue but no different.

Annoyingly this is a tricky subject to research due to so many people forgetting to set the Sorting property.

EDIT: Not sure if relevant but the form is called with `ShowDialog()`

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$LVserverlist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$form.Controls.Add($LVserverlist)
    $LVserverlist.Dock = "Fill"
    $LVserverlist.View = "Details"
    $LVserverlist.Sorting = "Ascending"
    $LVserverlist.Add_ColumnClick({ $LVserverlist.sort(); $LVserverlist.Items[0].Text = "Working?" })
    $LVserverlist.Columns.Add("Name", 200, "Left") | Out-Null

0..10 | Foreach-Object {
    $LVItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
    $LVItem.Text = (Get-Random -Maximum 1000).ToString()
    $LVserverlist.Items.Add($LVItem) | Out-Null
}

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Could be a scoping issue. Please show us your code

Comment: I have around a thousand lines of code. All that is relevant is that the ListView is in a Splitter within a Splitter within a Form, which is shown with `ShowDialog()`. If I add `Sort()` to any OnClick event it does nothing, but the rest of the code in the event runs fine. It doesn't matter if I pass the ListView as a parameter or use the global reference, I can add and change items in it fine.

Comment: Cook up a small application that reproduces the error then, and post that :) (please see [the `MVCE` section of the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Added code replicating the issue. Click the column, first item changes to "Working?" as expected but no sort. Close the form, call `$LVserverlist.Sort()` from the prompt, show the form again, list is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never did find a solution to getting Sort() to work, ended up with this workaround (which is a bit more flexible anyway):

```
Param
(
    [System.Windows.Forms.ListView]$sender,
    $column
)
$temp = $sender.Items | Foreach-Object { $_ }

$sender.Items.Clear()
$sender.Items.AddRange(($temp | Sort-Object -Property @{ Expression={ $_.SubItems[$column].Text } }))
```

Note that on the ListView the `Sorting` property needs to be set to None otherwise the items will be added back alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

coller event

```
$MyListView.add_ColumnClick({SortListView $this $_.Column})
```

Sort function whit memorize the lastest Order :

```
function SortListView {
    Param(
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListView]$sender,
        $column
    )
    $temp = $sender.Items | Foreach-Object { $_ }
    $Script:SortingDescending = !$Script:SortingDescending
    $sender.Items.Clear()
    $sender.ShowGroups = $false
    $sender.Sorting = 'none'
    $sender.Items.AddRange(($temp | Sort-Object -Descending:$script:SortingDescending -Property @{ Expression={ $_.SubItems[$column].Text } }))
}
```

Comment: Perfect - is there a way to sort by column even if ListViewGroups are used?

Comment: This works great. Could you explain this line by line. I think I get most of it, but the last line in particular is giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with custom function [Sort-ListViewColumn](https://github.com/lazywinadmin/WinFormPS/blob/master/Archives/Sort-ListViewColumn.ps1)

```
$MyListView.Add_ColumnClick({
    param($sender,$e)
    # Sort as Text String (not [int])
    Sort-ListViewColumn -ListView $this -ColumnIndex $e.column
})
```

full function code :

```
function Sort-ListViewColumn
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Sort the ListView's item using the specified column.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Sort the ListView's item using the specified column.
        This function uses Add-Type to define a class that sort the items.
        The ListView's Tag property is used to keep track of the sorting.
    .PARAMETER ListView
        The ListView control to sort.
    .PARAMETER ColumnIndex
        The index of the column to use for sorting.

    .PARAMETER  SortOrder
        The direction to sort the items. If not specified or set to None, it will toggle.

    .EXAMPLE
        Sort-ListViewColumn -ListView $listview1 -ColumnIndex 0

    .NOTES
        SAPIEN Technologies, Inc.
        http://www.sapien.com/

#>
    param (
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListView]$ListView,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [int]$ColumnIndex,
        [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder]$SortOrder = 'None')

    if (($ListView.Items.Count -eq 0) -or ($ColumnIndex -lt 0) -or ($ColumnIndex -ge $ListView.Columns.Count))
    {
        return;
    }

    #region Define ListViewItemComparer
    try
    {
        $local:type = [ListViewItemComparer]
    }
    catch
    {
        Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies ('System.Windows.Forms') -TypeDefinition  @" 
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Collections;
    public class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int column;
        public SortOrder sortOrder;
        public ListViewItemComparer()
        {
            column = 0;
            sortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        public ListViewItemComparer(int column, SortOrder sort)
        {
            this.column = column;
            sortOrder = sort;
        }
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            if(column >= ((ListViewItem)x).SubItems.Count)
                return  sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? -1 : 1;

            if(column >= ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems.Count)
                return sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? 1 : -1;

            if(sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
                return String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[column].Text, ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[column].Text);
            else
                return String.Compare(((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[column].Text, ((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[column].Text);
        }
    }
"@ | Out-Null
    }
    #endregion

    if ($ListView.Tag -is [ListViewItemComparer])
    {
        #Toggle the Sort Order
        if ($SortOrder -eq [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder]::None)
        {
            if ($ListView.Tag.column -eq $ColumnIndex -and $ListView.Tag.sortOrder -eq 'Ascending')
            {
                $ListView.Tag.sortOrder = 'Descending'
            }
            else
            {
                $ListView.Tag.sortOrder = 'Ascending'
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $ListView.Tag.sortOrder = $SortOrder
        }

        $ListView.Tag.column = $ColumnIndex
        $ListView.Sort()#Sort the items
    }
    else
    {
        if ($Sort -eq [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder]::None)
        {
            $Sort = [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder]::Ascending
        }

        #Set to Tag because for some reason in PowerShell ListViewItemSorter prop returns null
        $ListView.Tag = New-Object ListViewItemComparer ($ColumnIndex, $SortOrder)
        $ListView.ListViewItemSorter = $ListView.Tag #Automatically sorts
    }
}
```

Comment: You made my day! I was looking for some hints to write my own and found a totally working solution! Just letting folks know this solution works.